# How adding a New line in print statement can change way of output?

Tags: c, for-loop

In a for loop, if i am adding new line then it is printing at each iteration, And if i am just giving comma, means i want to print count down in one line, then it is waiting for completion of for loop.
Which part i am missing?

Following code will print the latest count down after every iteration completed (because of '\n')

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int x;
    for (x =0; x< 10; x++) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("Fire!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Following code will not print the latest count down, but will print when everything is done (may be because of ',')

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int x;
    for (x =0; x< 10; x++) {
        printf("%d, ", x);
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("Fire!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: is it something related to stdout buffer?

Comment: A buffer is used to reduce calling times and make the program more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flush the `stdout` buffer explicitly:

```
for (x =0; x< 10; x++) {
    printf("%d, ", x);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your guess in the comment is correct, it's because output is buffered. If you want the output immediately then you have to flush the buffers with the [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) function after `printf`.

Comment: just one query @JoachimPileborg , Why "\n" is working fine? Is new line make the buffers to flush?

Comment: @Vishwadeep Yes, `stdout` is line buffered if it's connected to a terminal.

Comment: @Vishwadeep Yes, the newline flushes the buffer.